# Data validation in excel, automatic value insert in adjacent cell

Tags: excel

is it possible to add data validation dropdown in column A, whereas the adjacent cell in column B would automatically be filled with a set value corresponding to the choice made in the column A dropdown?

I am not looking for another dropdown, but a preset value.

Comment: Yes, could be =Vlookup() as your solution

Comment: =vlookup is the solution, thank you!